# Объединение трёх запросов в один

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть 3 запроса и в них код очень похож, Можно ли сделать из них 1 запрос?

1) Показывает сколько статей в каждой категории

```
SELECT category.name, count(question.name) 
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN question 
ON category.id = question.cat_id 
GROUP BY category.name
```

2) Показывает, сколько вопросов опубликовано в каждом разделе.
Если статус = 1, значит опубликовано

```
SELECT category.name, count(question.status) 
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN question 
ON category.id = question.cat_id  AND question.status = 1 
GROUP BY category.name
```

3) Показывает, сколько вопросов без ответов, в каждом разделе

```
SELECT category.name, count(question.answer) 
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN question 
ON category.id = question.cat_id  AND question.answer = "" 
GROUP BY category.name
```

Comment: UNION / UNION ALL  с каким-нибудь разделителем между ними (если требуется конечно понять где данные от какого именно запроса)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT category.name
     , COUNT(question.name) 
     , SUM(question.status = 1)
     , SUM(question.answer = "")
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN question 
ON category.id = question.cat_id 
GROUP BY category.name
```

Запрос написан для MySQL. Если используется другая СУБД, замените `SUM(condition)` на `SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Answer (score -2):

Должна получиться выборка:

```
SELECT (SELECT ...), (SELECT ...), ...
```